# ArrayList not persisting between methods

Tags: java, jsf, ejb, javabeans

I'm trying to load a csv file into an arrayList to later break it up and store it. Between my methods the arrayList is being reset to null. I'm confused as to the cause and would be grateful for any advice

```
package TestInput;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Bean {

    private String fileContent;
    private String fileContent2;
    private ArrayList<String> fileContentArray;
    private int counter = 0;

    public int getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }

    public void setCounter(int counter) {
        this.counter = counter;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getFileContentArray() {
        return fileContentArray;
    }

    public void setFileContentArray(ArrayList<String> fileContentArray) {
        this.fileContentArray = fileContentArray;
    }

    public String getFileContent() {
        return fileContent;
    }

    public void setFileContent(String fileContent) {
        this.fileContent = fileContent;
    }

    public String getFileContent2() {
        return fileContent2;
    }

    public void setFileContent2(String fileContent2) {
        this.fileContent2 = fileContent2;
    }

    public void upload() {

        File file = new File("/Users/t_sedgman/Desktop/FinalProject/test_output_data.rtf");
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        BufferedInputStream bis = null;
        DataInputStream dis = null;
        ArrayList<String> tempArray = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            // Here BufferedInputStream is added for fast reading.
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            dis = new DataInputStream(bis);

            // dis.available() returns 0 if the file does not have more lines.
            while (dis.available() != 0) {

                // this statement reads the line from the file and print it to
                // the console.
                tempArray.add(dis.readLine());
            }
            setFileContentArray(tempArray);
            // dispose all the resources after using them.

            fis.close();
            bis.close();
            dis.close();
            fileContent = fileContentArray.get((fileContentArray.size() - 2));

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void next() {
        ArrayList<String> tempArray = getFileContentArray();
        int size = fileContentArray.size();
        if (counter <= size) {
            counter++;
            fileContent2 = tempArray.get(counter);
        } else {
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Many Thanks

Tom

Comment: How are you invoking your methods?

Comment: Never use Deprecated method [DataInputStream#readLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readLine()). Find the correct method at the link itself.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Invoking using commandButtons from JSF page, output to textArea on same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try By marking your bean with `@ViewScoped/@SessionScoped`